# Listing docker images with associated containers

Tags: bash, docker

Using `docker image prune` we can remove dangling or unused images.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to list all images **used** by at least one container, also listing - for each image - the containers that are using them.

Is there some out-of-the-box command in Docker or should I write a script to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the output of `docker ps`:

```
docker ps -a | awk '{print "Image "$2" used by container "$1"" }'
```

this will print the name of the base image and the name of the container for all containers on your machine.

Comment: Just a quick edit. Should be
`docker ps -a | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "Image "$2" used by container "$1"" }'`

Comment: You can also do `docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}} {{.Names}} {{.ID}}"  | awk '{print "Image "$2" used by container "$1"" }'`

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating the answer suggested by **Paolo**, I created this script which matches pretty fine what I had in my mind:

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}} {{.Names}} {{.ID}}" | sort | awk '{print "Image "$1" used by container "$2" ("$3")" }'
```